# C++ Calling managed object method causes AccessViolationException

Tags: c++, managed-c++

I am using a managed dll in my program. I create a System::Object using the namespace in this dll

`public ref class Class1`

and this object has a public method:

`returnType getValue()`

which returns:

`public enum class returnType`

To use this method, I do the following:

```
// Initialize object
Class1^ firstInstance= gcnew Class1();
// Create empty return type
returnType^ returnedValue = returnType ::EmptyType;
// call method
returnedValue = firstInstance->getValue();
```

This code results an AccessViolationException at the line where I call the getValue method, with the explanation of "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt".

I am not familiar with C++ but seems it is a pointer error. I can use the same method from same object in C# without any issue as following:

```
Class1 firstInstance= new Class1();
returnType returnedValue = returnType.EmptyType;
returnedValue = firstInstance.getValue();
```

What am I doing wrong in C++ code?

Comment: what does `getValue` do? please post the code

Comment: @slawekwin, I have only the dll. I know only that getValue() method returns returnType. No more information I have.

Comment: There's not enough information here to give an answer, though I have to ask, does Class1 really need to be dynamically allocated?

Comment: @George, when I try to create the object using “Class1* firstInstance = new Class1();” and intellisense gives following error : “an ordinary pointer to a C++/CLI ref class or interface class is not allowed”. Unfortunately, I don’t have any other info about the dll. I have a poor documentation about it and its classes but there is nothing more than I wrote in the question. I know that c++ is much different than C# but I have only wondered if one can find out the problem looking at the c# code since there is no problem to create and use the same object there.

Comment: Quite likely it is to do with the way the DLL is loaded e.g. missing configuration files, failed to initialize properly, something like that. It may have nothing to do with the way you are calling it..
What information does the debugger give you? What if you step in to `gcnew Class1()`? What if you step into `firstInstance->getValue()`?

Comment: @Lati I just mean, does it not let you do something like this in C++? : `Class1 firstInstance;`
`returnType returnedValue = EmptyType;`
`returnedValue = firstInstance.getValue();`

Comment: @George, I get the same AccessViolationException.

Comment: @Ben, I also wonder if I have loaded the dll wrong. What I have done is to add Additional Library Directory with the dll in the Project properties and added the namespace in the cpp file. I have actually no problem to create the object but using the object methods. I cannot step into the line, it just steps over when I press F11.

Comment: right-click, step into specific. You may have to turn off "Just my code"

Comment: Another useful trick is to use SysInternals processMonitor, to monitor the activity of the process while running. If you see "file not found" results this may possibly be a clue to a missing configuration file or something of that nature. Of course these are all guesses because I have no idea what your DLL is or what it does.

Comment: @Ben, Step in doesn't work, it asks for *.pdb file related to the dll which I don't have. I will try SysInternals. I also have no idea about the dll and since 2 days trying to find out how to make it run. The same dll runs smoothly in C# though. Problem is specific to C++.

Comment: Tell it to go ahead without the pdb, and show assembly instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130691/discussion-between-lati-and-ben).